# Проблемы с эмулятором

Tags: android-studio, эмулятор

При запуске эмулятора студия его не видит.

При закрытии эмулятора - ошибка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При закрытии экрана ошибки - прекращена работа программы emulator-crash-service.exe
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А сам эмулятор работает нормально?

Comment: Эмулятор работает отлично. Только никаких признаков подключения к студии. Например не отображает ни процессы в лог, ни ... короче ничего. И при запуске приложения, подключенных эмуляторов не видит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В моем случае помогло установить более старые версии SDK и Эмулятора

Answer (score 0):

Еще одно решение проблемы. В диспетчере задач Windows убиваю процесс adb.exe после запуска эмулятора.